# Guacamole RDP Remote App within a black box

Tags: rdp, remoteapp, guacamole

When I connect to a RemoteApp using the following code:

```
@Override
protected GuacamoleTunnel createTunnel(Session session, EndpointConfig config) throws GuacamoleException {

    // Create our configuration
    GuacamoleConfiguration guacConfig = new GuacamoleConfiguration();
    guacConfig.setProtocol("rdp");
    guacConfig.setParameter("security", "any");
    guacConfig.setParameter("hostname", HOST);
    guacConfig.setParameter("port", PORT);
    guacConfig.setParameter("username", USER);
    guacConfig.setParameter("password", SECRET);
    guacConfig.setParameter("ignore-cert", "true");
    guacConfig.setParameter("remote-app", "||calc");

    // Connect to guacd
    GuacamoleSocket socket = new ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket(
            new InetGuacamoleSocket(GUACD_HOST, GUACD_PORT),
            guacConfig
    );

    return new SimpleGuacamoleTunnel(socket);
}
```

I connect just fine, but the remote app is displayed in a big black box.

[image]

Is there any way to crop the display to the remote-app only?

Also, closing the page does not close the remote-app on the server, so when I'd refresh the page, i'd end up with two calculators, any tips on that too?

Answer (score 0):

The black box you see is a "desktop", or whatever is contained below the remote app. You can use "width" and "height" parameters to set the desktop size. The list of available RDP options is here: https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/0.9.5/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#rdp

Alternatively, you can set the application to start maximized and occupy the whole desktop. You can check here how to set this up: https://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip201.htm.

Comment: Any way I can remove this 'desktop'?. From what I understand a remoteapp usually runs integrated on a windows machine. Guacamole must have implemented this 'desktop' to emulate it in a way, there should be ways to remove it. Additionally, forcing a maximized window that way only applies to shortcuts (.lnk), not executables the remoteapp registry typically contains.

Comment: I have created a file to access calculator app remotely called calculator.rdp in D:\temp folder.can you tell me the way to configure RemoteApp in the default guacamole-client application provided in Guacamole site ? I mean there are some fields to give details like programs,working directory,parameter. Could you please tell me that what should i mention on those fields?